# Why isn't onPrepare finished when onComplete starts? [protractor, jasmine]

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor, jasmine2.0

My Protractor tests are ending with error messages like `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\QA\test-results\chrome\junitresults.xml'`.

But when I check the `c:\QA\test-results\chrome\` folder, a brand new `junitresults.xml` is right there.

So I wonder if the `onComplete` function is getting run before the `xml` file has finished being generated.

(Since each `onPrepare` *does* create a `junitresults.xml`, the *next* time the test runs, the `onComplete` function finds and uses the previous test's file. So the `html` file created is always about 30 minutes outdated. If I delete the old `junitresults.xml` and start over, I get the error message again.)

What can I do?

```
onPrepare: function() {

    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();    
    capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
        browser.browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.replace(/ /g,"-");
        browser.browserVersion = caps.caps_.version; 
        browserName = browser.browserName;
        browser.reportPath = 'c:/QA/test-results/' + browser.browserName + '/';
    }). then(function(caps) {
            var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({    
                consolidateAll: true,
                savePath: 'c:/QA/test-results/' + browser.browserName + '/',
                filePrefix: 'junitresults'
        }));
    });

    return browser.browserName, browser.browserVersion, browser.reportPath;
},


onComplete: function() {

  var HTMLReport = require('jasmine-xml2html-converter');
  // Call custom report for html output
  testConfig = {
    reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
    outputPath: browser.reportPath,
    seleniumServer: 'default',
    applicationUrl: browser.baseUrl,
    testBrowser: browser.browserName + ' v.' + browser.browserVersion
  };
  new HTMLReport().from(browser.reportPath + 'junitresults.xml', testConfig);

  console.log("... aaaannnnd... done.");
},
```